# SF short story about a dome with a kid and a robot

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this at least 25 years ago, so before 2000. I can't remember too much about the story, except that it really captivated my imagination - these are the points I remember:

1. The boy lived in a translucent dome his entire life.
2. I think he was under the impression there was no life outside the dome and going outside would be fatal.
3. He had a robot friend, not very advanced if I can remember correctly.
4. I think there was one scene where the robot gave his life for the kid to escape the dome. If I remember correctly the hole or door he was escaping through was closing are falling in and the robot put it's body in the line to keep it open.

Anybody have any idea what the story was?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember where you read this?  In a magazine or an anthology?

Comment: I am pretty sure it was in a thick SF short stories omnibus collection and must have been in the 90's. I suspect it might have been in the same bundle with Microcosmic God.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9580832-the-boy-at-the-end-of-the-world matches, but it's too recent.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yeah, that's not it.